# Attaching private documents to contact

Tags: wordpress, contacts, custom-fields

Is it possible to create a custom File field for contacts, but somehow limit the view to only certain types of users?

Use case would be attaching an employment contract containing private information such as salary. A user that has the ability to view/edit contacts, should not be able to see this File, but only an HR manager.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can control access to specific custom fields with [ACLs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#native-civicrm-acls).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [documents extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/documents)?

Comment: has been a great extension for some of our projects